# Ansible share variables between hosts during run-time

Tags: ansible

I am using Ansible 2.5.4 and I need to share variables between hosts.

I tried many examples that I saw online (share with set_fact or using a dummy host) and it is all not working.

Maybe I am doing something different. This is my playbook:

```
    ---
    - hosts: master[0]
      tasks:
      - name: generate kubernetes BootrapToken
        command: kubeadm token generate
        register: generate_token_result
    
      - set_fact: token="{{generate_token_result}}"
    
    
    - hosts: new       # requires creating new group in inventory.cfg named new
      tasks:
      - name: include docker-host role
        include_role:
          name: docker-host
        when: not skip_nodes_setup
      - name: include kubernetes-host role
        include_role:
          name: kubernetes-host
        when: not skip_nodes_setup
      - name: include kubernetes-operator role
        include_role:
          name: kubernetes-operator
        when: not skip_nodes_setup
      - name: join node to kubernetes cluster
        command: "kubeadm join --token {{ hostvars['master[0]']['token']['stdout'] }} --discovery-token-unsafe-skip-ca-verification {{ hostvars['kubernetes_machines']['kube_apiserver'] }}"
```

I am getting the following error:

```
The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: "hostvars['master[0]']" is undefined
```

The first task is able to run on master[0] but the second task does not recognize that host.

Adding the `inventory.cfg`:

```
    [kubernetes_machines:vars]
    kube_apiserver=10.82.72.54:6443

    [kubernetes_machines:children]
    masters
    nodes
    new

    [masters]
    srv12

    [nodes]
    srv13

    [new]
    prd4
```

Comment: Post the inventory.

Comment: I added the inventory

Comment: `- hosts: master[0]` maybe `masters`, since you have no `master` in inventory.

Comment: @eran *hosts: master[0]* can't work with this inventory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ask for `"hostvars['master[0]']"`, you've got the entire `master[0]` inside quotes so you're referring to a host with the literal name `master[0]`.  If you mean the first member of the `master` hostgroup, you need a variable reference, not a string, and you'll need to use the `groups` variable (and you need to remember your hostgroup is named `masters` not `master`):

```
hostvars[groups.masters.0]
```

You can find relevant documentation [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#accessing-information-about-other-hosts-with-magic-variables).

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [Playbook Basics](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#hosts-and-users)

> The hosts line is a list of one or more groups or host patterns

Pattern **master[0]** doesn't match hostname **master[0]**. If the hostname is **master0** then the hostvars reference should be

```
hostvars['master0']
```

It's not clear why **hosts: master[0]** works. It should not according to the documentation. **hosts: master.0** which should be the same doesn't work.

Comment: it is supposed tb be the first master in masters host group of the inventory